# Android browser does not load XHTML Jquery Mobile page

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, xhtml

Consider the following `XHTML` page, `page1.xhtml`, which contains Jquery Mobile scripting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 

        <title>Page 1</title> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    </head> 

    <body> 

        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Page Title</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">   
                <a href="page2.xhtml">Go to page 2</a>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

    </body>
</html>
```

When the link is clicked, `page2.xhtml` is not loaded. (only the loading animator image is displayed, that's it)

This problem is only with `XHTML` pages, not with HTML.

I tested with Samsung GT-S5302 device and some Android (both phone and tablet) emulators.

Comment: Why do you use the `.xhtml` extension? An HTML page can have the `.html` extension and still be valid XHTML, as this is set in the doctype/html tag.

Comment: I am using JSF which prefer XHTML over HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned jQuery Mobile has a problem with XHTML.

Your problem can be fixed by removing this line, but I dont know if you are going to like it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And here's a proof: http://www.fajrunt.org/page1.xhtml

**EDIT :**

Main problem here is that webkit browsers are wrapping whole HTML inside an another DIV. Dont ask me why, and existance of  is causing this problem to occur.

Comment: Of course this is a working solution, but I am little scared of doing this, because this may cause some other problems with Jquery Mobile:-).

Comment: I was wondering the same thing few hours ago. It took me some time but I have tested my jQM/Phonegap app without <!DOCTYPE html>  and it worked well. Only browser I didnt tried was IE. So you are safe to go if you are going to create a mobile app.